# Unit test a function which performs a selector and wait until its done

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, nsthread, ocmock

I have a `MyService` class which inherits `NSThread`:

header:

```
@interface MyService : NSThread {
  -(void) startMe;
  -(void) doTask;
  ...
}
```

implementation:

```
@implementation MyService
  -(void)startMe {
   [self start];
  }
  -(void) doTask {
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkData:) onThread:self withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
  }

  -(void) checkData {
    ...
    // NOTE: dataChecked is an instance variable.
    dataChecked = YES;
  }
@end
```

I want to unit test the above `-(void)doTask` and verify that `-(void)checkData` is really called. I use [OCMock library](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to partially mock `MyService` & tried the following way:

```
-(void) testCheckData {
  // partial mock MyService
  id myService = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[MyService getInstance]];
  [myService startMe];

  // function to test
  [myService doTask];

  // I wait 2 seconds for checkData to finish its work
  dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // When running this test case, these code is never called & test passed successfully, WHY?
        NSLog(@"Check if checkData does its work");
        XCTAssertTrue([self isDataChecked]);
    });
}
```

**Two questions:**

**Q1.** As you see above, in my test case, I call `-(void)doTask` & **wait 2 seconds**, expect the `-(void)checkData` is executed, then assert the result, but when running test case, it doesn't run the block in `dispatch_after(...)` & test passed successfully, WHY it doesn't run the block?

**Q2.** What is the right way to unit test a function like `-(void)doTask` which invokes NSObject#[performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:)?

Comment: You need to use `XCTestExpectation` and `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:` here is a pretty good explanation on it https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/

Comment: is the timeout parameter in second or millisecond?

Comment: Its in seconds if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

If you can't change `doTask` to make it testable, you have to use an `XCTestExpectation` to wait for the test to complete.  Also, instead of waiting a preset amount of time, you should busy-loop, checking the variable on each iteration.  You can set a timeout on the expectation to trigger a failure after some reasonable amount of time.

```
// setup expectation    
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    while (dataChecked == NO);
    // signal expectation
});

// wait for expectation
```

**Q2**

If you have to know the implementation of the method to successfully test it, it's not a good candidate for unit testing.  It shouldn't matter how the method being tested invokes other methods.  It only matters if side-effects are synchronous- or asynchronously completed.

Comment: I did what you suggested in Q1, but no matter how many seconds I set, the wait for expectation part just return immediately without really waiting. But if I set a break point at the "waitForExpectationsWithTimeout" part & press continue button it then does wait. Any idea why?

Comment: I made a new question about this problem, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845892/unit-test-async-function-by-using-xctestexpectation-but-it-doesnt-wait-for-the