# unit test async function by using XCTestExpectation but it doesn't wait for the seconds I set

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I have a `MyService` class which inherits `NSThread`:

header:

```
@interface MyService : NSThread {
  -(void) startMe;
  -(void) doTask;
  ...
}
```

implementation:

```
@implementation MyService
  -(void)startMe {
   [self start];
  }
  -(void) doTask {
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkData:) onThread:self withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
  }

  -(void) checkData {
    ...
    // NOTE: dataChecked is an instance variable.
    dataChecked = YES;
  }
@end
```

I want to unit test the above `-(void)doTask` and verify that `-(void)checkData` is really called. I use [OCMock library](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/) to partially mock `MyService`.

Inspired by [this tutorial (use XCTestExpectation)](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/), I tried the following way:

```
       -(void) testCheckData {
          // partial mock MyService
          id myService = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[MyService getInstance]];
          [myService startMe];

          // function to test
          [myService doTask];

          // I setup expectation
          XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"data checked"];

         // run assertion asynchronisely
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            XCTAssertTrue([self isDataChecked]);
            // expectation fulfill
            [expectation fulfill];
        });

        // wait for 5 seconds
        [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Timeout Error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
       }
```

However, when I run my test, the [waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCTestCase.html#//api/name/waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:) doesn't work, I mean it doesn't wait for 5 seconds, the assertion part run immediately after function under test get called. Why it doesn't wait 5 seconds?

**====== UPDATE ======**

I also tried not using async block :

```
-(void) testCheckData {
        // partial mock MyService
        id myService = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[MyService getInstance]];
        [myService startMe];

        // function to test
        [myService doTask];

        // I setup expectation
        XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"data checked"];

       // run assertion
       XCTAssertTrue([self isDataChecked]);
       // expectation fulfill
       [expectation fulfill];

       // wait for 5 seconds
       [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
          if (error) {
              NSLog(@"Timeout Error: %@", error);
          }
      }];
    }
```

But I still get the same problem, there is no waiting 5 seconds, the test return immediately, why?

**===== AND =====**

I might be wroing, if we ignore my update above & back to see my original code **using async block**.I think `waitForExpectations:5` should do the waiting that I don't need to use `while` loop, why I think this way is because of that [tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/).

If we check that tutorial, it firstly show the **old stye of using while loop** to wait, then, it changed to expectation style which **doesn't use any while loop**, what it does is set expectation->start work ( assert in the completion block of its work), it also has the `waitForExpectations:` code, which looks exactly the same as my code **with the async block**. I want to understand why my original code looks the same as the tutorial but doesn't work. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved.

I should use `dispatch_after` insteand of `dispatch_async`, because I don't have a completion block in my function under test while the example in that tutorial has one. So, I need to change to this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        XCTAssert(...);
        [expectation fulfill];
});
```

If you want to use `dispatch_async` please check @Avi's comment, use a `while` loop in the async block to wait.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you begin to **waitForExpectations**, your dispatch_async will get a chance to run.  It will assert that your data have been checked, and then -- regardless of whether your data has been checked or not -- it marks the expectation as fulfilled.  Once fulfilled, we no longer need to wait and we can finish.

That's probably not what you want to do, but it's what the code says.

Comment: But how to fix my problem? I need it to wait 5 seconds before the assertion.

Comment: As I wrote in your original question, you should be looping until the data is checked.  Only then should you signal the expectation and return from the asynchronous block.  After the wait call you can assert whether the data was checked.

Comment: @Avi, I don't understand now, according to the tutorial : https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/ isn't the XCTestExpectation thing is supposed to get rid of old style way of using while loop to test async function? but now I still need to use while loop, then what's the benefit of using XCTestExpectation ?

Comment: You are confused about what should be checked in the loop.  You posted code that is asserting from the asynchronous block.  That is the wrong thing to do.  First you should perform the work, then you assert that the work was done properly.  The while loop is waiting for the work to finish, and is only done this way because your asynchronous method has no notification system.  It requires polling because it was written that way.  That doesn't make polling good; it makes it necessary.

Comment: @Avi, I thought the same thing, and already tried removing async block, but I get the same problem, no waiting, test returns immediately. Please check my update in my post.

Comment: Everything is linear in that new code.  Why would you expect it to wait when you explicitly signal it just before waiting?  It's clearly already signaled by the time you even start waiting.  The code I wrote in reply to your other question shows the proper way of handling this.  I don't know why you haven't tried it.

Comment: @Avi, I am confused about your words, please patiently read my following words: I could try that code you replied in my other question, but I want to understand why I need to use while loop while using XCTtestExpectation, as I mentioned according to that tutorial, there shouldn't be a while loop. Since you are saying we need while loop because I am using async block, now I remove the async block, I want to know why it still doesn't work? I want to make this clear. Hope you understand my point now. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are really bad for this, but here goes... the proper sequence for a unit test is: perform work -> test result of work.  When the work is asynchronous, it becomes: start work -> wait for work to finish -> test result of work.  What you are doing is: start work -> test result of work.  You don't wait for the work to complete.  Expectations are designed to allow you to wait for the completion, but you insist on using them incorrectly.  Correct sequence: setup expectation -> start work -> wait for work to complete -> signal expectation (fulfilled) -> check result of work.

Comment: @Avi, thanks for clarification, I think the point I might have misunderstood is "wait for work to complete", I think `waitForExpectations:5` already do this that I don't need to use while loop, why I think this way is all because of that tutorial, if you check that tutorial, it firstly show the old stye of using while loop to wait, then, it changed to expectation style which doesn't use any while loop, what it does is set expectation->start work ( assert in the completion block of its work) , then it has the  `waitForExpectations` code, it looks the same as my code with the async block.

Comment: They are asserting in the block, but the difference is that in their example, the calling of the block means the work is done.  In your example, that is not the case because your `doTask` method doesn't have a completion handler.  You have no choice but to poll for completion because your API is poor.  If you can, change the API.  Your test and your app will be better for it.

Comment: @Avi, yep, you are right, I solved the problem, in my previous question, my original code use `dispatch_after`, your answer there suggested using `dispatch_async` with a while loop. If I change back to `dispatch_after`, it works without `while` loop.

Comment: Using a `dispatch_after` is bad, because it implicitly assumes a maximum time for how long the process will take.  In a unit test like this, such an assumption is impossible to avoid, unless you want to allow the test to take a very long time.  However, this is why you have a timeout on the expectation.

Comment: @Avi, you have a point. But I also found http://savvyapps.com/blog/ios-expectations-test-async-functions-without-callback-method  which shows exactly my case & it suggested to use `dispatch_after`. Anyhow, it might be personal preference because anyhow we have to explictly set a waiting time before assertion. I really don't see the difference between using `dispatch_after` & `dispatch_asyc` with a while loop. We set the waiting time anyway.

Comment: Now you have two separate places in your test method with a timeout.  Sure, it's a small block of code, and well-isolated, but why perpetuate a bad coding practice just because?

Comment: @Avi, I understand your point. In my project, I am creating a wrapper function which takes a timeout parameter & inside the function, I apply this parameter to the two places. And all test cases call this wrapper function. So, for my specific case, test case only need to pass one timeout to this function. But I understand your point & agree that in general, it is a bad practice to have two places set timeout.